# Existing IONIC 1 Project migrate to IBM Worklight (MobileFirst Platform 'MFP')

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I just wonder how to migrate the existing Ionic (v1) project (android & IOS) to MobileFirst Platform (MFP).

Because what I realised, all the structure is totally different.

Anyone got an idea? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Check if you are using MobileFirst Foundation 8.0:**

Integrating MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 in Ionic v1 based apps https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/

Integrating MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 in Ionic 2 based apps: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/17/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic2-based-apps/

> **Check if you are using IBM MobileFirst 7.1:**

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/01/13/ionic-hybrid-mobile-app-using-mobilefirst-platform-7-1-cli/

You need to install **mobilefirst_cli_installer_7.1.0** and you can download it from here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_7.1.0.zip

and then follow this tutorial : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/using-cli-to-create-build-and-manage-mobilefirst-project-artifacts/

Comment: Great! Thanks.. But unfortunately I'm still cant run 'mfp cordova create' and getting this error:

'Error: Implementation for this cordova subcommand has failed or not been provided: create.'

Comment: @Safrul  You need to install to installl mfp cli 7.1. Please check the update answer.

Comment: which cordova & ionic version you are using ?

Comment: MFP Cli 7.1   ||   Cordova 7.0.1   || Ionic Cli 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

Ionic is based on Cordova a.e. hybrid JS/HTML (Web View) based infrastructure.

From [What is IBM MobileFirst post](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2014/11/19/so-what-is-ibm-mobilefirst/):

> Does the hybrid approach leverage Apache Cordova?  **YES**.

So go ahead and good luck

Also Ref:

[Integrating IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation SDK in Cordova applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/)

Comment: Thanks.. I tried to run 'mfp cordova' command and I'm getting this error:

Error: Unrecognized or empty cordova subcommand: 
Error: Implementation for this cordova subcommand has failed or not been provided: undefined.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Safrul  Im not familiar  with IBM MobileFirst but suggest you to create empty Ionic project from scratch and integrate with MobileFirst to avoid noise. After its done it can be easy to integrate your original project

Comment: Got it... Okay I will figure out. But your information quite useful.Thanks :)